# The converse of a corollary to the intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

A corollary to the Intermediate Value Theorem is that if $f(x)$ is a continuous real-valued function on an interval $I$, then the set $f(I)$ is also an interval or a single point.

Is the converse true? Suppose $f(x)$ is defined on an interval $I$ and that $f(I)$ is an interval. Is $f(x)$ continuous on $I$?

Would the answer change if $f(x)$ is one-to-one?

Comment: A single point is an interval, albeit degenerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion is not true even if $f$ is one to one.  Consider the function on $[-1,1]$ defined by $f(x) = x$ for $x \not=-1,0,1 $, and $f(-1) = 0, f(0) = 1, f(1)=-1$.  Then this function is not continuous, but is one to one and the range $f(I)$ is the interval $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bad counterexample: [Conway's base-$13$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) takes *all values* on any (non-degenerate) interval. (This is stronger than just asking that $f(I)$ is an interval: You get that $f(J)$ is an interval for all intervals $J$. Note that requiring this removes the counterexamples offered in the other answers.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one converse:

> If $f$ is monotone and $f(I)$ is an interval, then $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

No to both! Define $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2})$, and $f(x)=\frac{3}{2}-x$ for $x\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$. $f$ is injective and $f([0,1])$ is an interval, but $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: I am not quite sure whether the function is continuous. Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: The function is not continuous at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}^-}f(x)=1/2$, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}^+}f(x)=1$.

Comment: O I see. I misread.